# Proving logical equivalence without truth tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been trying to understand the solution for quite a while now, but I still don't understand the way this is solved.

```
Q: Prove φ1,φ2 |= ψ <=> φ1 |= φ2 -> ψ <=> |= (φ1 ^ φ2) -> ψ

A: The first equivalence is proven in 2 steps:

1) φ1,φ2 |= ψ => φ1 |= φ2 -> ψ
2) φ1 |= φ2 -> ψ => φ1,φ2 |= ψ

1) Let V be a valuation so that V(φ1) = 1.
If V(φ2) = 0, then V(φ2 -> ψ) = 1. If V(φ2) = 1, then given the proposition (φ1,φ2 |= ψ) this means that V(ψ = 1, and also V(φ2 -> ψ) = 1.

This together proves that φ1 |= φ2 -> ψ.

2) Let V be a valuation so that Vφ1) = V(φ2) = 1.
Given V(φ1) = 1 and given the proposition, this means that V(φ2 -> ψ) = 1. Because V(φ2) = 1, this means that V(ψ) = 1.

This proves that φ1,φ2 |= ψ
```

I don't understand that we can use 2).
If we take a V(φ2) = 0, this means that V(φ2 -> ψ) = 1. Equivalence means that each model of the left side needs to have a model of the right side, doesn't it?

So why can we use 2) when the models don't match?

Comment: I'm not very much into logic, but what would seem to me - if V is a valuation with $V(\varphi_2) = 0$, $V(\varphi_1) = 1$, there are two options (both satysfying  $V(\varphi_2 \rightarrow \psi) = 1$): either $V(\psi) = 1$, which is OK, since then the conclusion holds, or $V(\psi) = 0$, but this just tells you nothing (V is not a model, since $V(\varphi_2) = 0$.

Comment: @pepa.dvorak You are correct, I have a problem understanding models. Your comment made this equivalence clear, but I'm still struggling with other, more complex exercises. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it (your comment solved my question).

Comment: Propositional valuations are truth tables, even if you try to hide it behind cryptic language.

Comment: @DanielVYes, but these are assignments to teach us to cope with more parts than are feasibly written out in a truth table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very much into logic, but what would seem to me - if V is a valuation with $V(\varphi_2)=0, V(\varphi_1)=1$, there are two options (both satysfying $V(\varphi_2\rightarrow\psi)=1)$: either $V(\psi)=1$, which is OK, since then the conclusion holds, or $V(\psi)=0$, but this just tells you nothing (V is not a model, since $V(\varphi_2)=0$).